# Sorting an array according to an element inside this array

Tags: arrays, ruby, sorting

I need to order my array according to an element of it, the reference element can vary.
For example, I would like the 3 to become the first element of the array and the 1, 2 to be put at the end.

- *array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]*
- *new_array = [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]*

The element may vary. If I start from 5, the behavior must be the same: the elements that precede are placed at the end, so I will have :

- *new_array = [5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4]*

Comment: Using `Array#rotate`, as suggested by @Ceribe, would be the Ruby way, but you could also write `arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; n = arr.size; arr.each_index.map { |i| arr[(i+2) % n] } #=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely use `#rotate` for this in actual use, but as an alternative, you could do something like `#shift` and `#push` until the desired element is at the beginning of the array.

```
def rotate(arr, elem)
    arr2 = arr.clone
    arr2.push(arr2.shift) until arr2.first == elem
    arr2
end
```

```
irb(main):026:0> arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
irb(main):027:0> rotate(arr, 3)
=> [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
irb(main):028:0> arr
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Clearly, if `elem` is *not* in `arr`, this will run forever. You could implement some kind of check to ensure this doesn't happen, but that's just one reason you shouldn't actually do this as anything other than a learning exercise.

One approach would be to find the index of `elem` in `arr` and shift/push that many times. The `&.` operator may be useful in that situation to deal with the possibility of not finding `elem` in `arr`.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly you want to rotate the array.

```
array
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
array.rotate(2) # or array.rotate(array.index(3))
# [3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
```

https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/Array/rotate

Comment: Yes. But 2 isn't an input. So `array.rotate(3-1)` or `array.rotate(array.index(3))`, then, right?

Comment: Yes, I was just explaining how rotate works. To make "3" the first element it should be done as you said.